# Am I allowed to ask questions about Vampire: The Masquerade -- Bloodlines plot here, or should I go for Arqade?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, world-of-darkness, video-games

[*Vampire: the Masquerade — Bloodlines*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire:_The_Masquerade_%E2%80%93_Bloodlines) is a PC game from 2004. This game is very old, and does not have an active community on Arqade. There are forums, but forums aren't as good as SE. If I want plot clarifications based on oWoD canon, I would benefit from expertise in the tabletop roleplaying game more than from computer game expertise.

So, may I ask here about plot clarifications (such as "How could the protagonist develop immunity to Dominate") here, or should I go to Arqade just because it's a computer game?

Comment: Is the plot of the game "canon"? I can't remember.... If so, answers from the lore might be possible, at least.

Comment: @Patta The plot of the game is not canon, but it is set in the canonical Anarch Free State, and very....VERY vaguely follows the tabletop system.  Kind of.  A little.  It is much safer to say that VtM:B is inspired by the table top game than anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I think this depends heavily on how the question is phrased.

Questions that are *purely* about the plot belong on Arqade. Questions that try to understand the plot of the game from the perspective of the pencil & paper rulebooks would probably be OK, on the other hand.

For example, "What in-game justification is given for the protagonist's immunity to Dominate?" would be off-topic; it has nothing to do with the pencil & paper RPGs that are this stack's focus. On the other hand, "The protagonist of V:tM Bloodlines seems to be immune to Dominate; how could that be accomplished in the V:tM rules?" *would* be on-topic, because it's about the pencil & paper V:tM rules.

Comment: [scifi.se] might also be a good fit for lore-oriented questions. There only seems to be one V:tM Bloodlines question on there ([What did happened on the Elizabeth Dane?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34443/15502)) but that's not to say there aren't people around who'd answer questions if they were available.

Answer (score 4):

If  you want to ask more like [the kind of question you asked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/96472/4), you should just go to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) or [Scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).

The original version of the question was really not appropriate for our site. It reads like this in essence: “Please explain to me how this thing could've worked that happened in this video game, using the tabletop game rules which the video game only kinda-sorta uses, and preferably only using features that also showed up in the video game.”

This is seeking an explanation about the video game from someone who's an expert on the video game. You're *trying* to stretch it into source material that's not all that relevant — the tabletop game rules, which you acknowledged yourself the game blended with another ruleset so that it's not *really* using those tabletop rules at all but instead some beast unique unto itself — because you really want an answer.

But we're not the appropriate experts to consult for this. Explaining a video game on the video game's terms is not our business. We can't give you a good answer about the video game, and a answer from us based on material the video game *isn't really using* isn't going to do much good for you or anyone.

---

I [edited your question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/96472/5) so that it would no longer be a weirdly twisted pseudo-TTRPG-but-actually-video-game question, mostly to show you at what point it'd be a functional appropriate question for our site: something happened in a video game, but now let's ask about it on the roleplaying game's terms, drawing on TTRPG expertise and producing an answer useful to TTRPG players, instead of something reliant on and for the video game's players. I'm not sure it will give you the answers you want about the video game's events, though.